# check if event exists before adding it from google sheet to calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've got a script that updates a calendar from a sheet. 
Is there a way of getting the eventID of an event i would add to the calendar if it didn't exist ?

what would be the ID of the event to be created with (title, start, stop)

I can then check it against the eventIDs of existing events and add , if not already there.
i think this would be quicker than checking existing events for matching all properties before either adding the new one , or just moving on

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the IDs work the way you seem to think they do (as some sort of hash of the information inside them). Can you check the date you want for the title you want? I think that would be enough.

this is a script to get you started, it finds the next occurence of "Sample Meeting" in the next 20 days. You can easily narrow the scope to a single day and then add an "else" that creates the new meeting.

```
function insertItem() {


      var fromDate = new Date(); //This is Today
      var toDate = new Date();
      toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+20);
      Logger.log("From "+fromDate+" to "+toDate);
   var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);


  for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++)
    {
      var ev = events[i];
      var title = calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).getTitle();


      if (title.indexOf("Sample Meeting")>-1){
        var start = ev.getStartTime();
        Logger.log("Found Team Meeting");

          var id = ev.getId();
          var date = ev.getStartTime();
          var desc = ev.getDescription();


          return;

          }


    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks - you are correct in  my mistaken assumption that the ID is generated from the input data . So checking title/times/contects will be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but its going to take a bit of work.

Event ids are auto-generated by default. [However, you can generate custom ids for an event as long as they conform to Google's format requirements](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#id). So, you'll have to manage the generation of these event ids yourself.

You will have to ensure that the id is unique, so you might want to base it on a combination of inputs related to the event.

Once you have some way of generating a unique id, you can use it to fetch an event directly by id, but you have to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) (the built-in service does not allow lookup by event id, but it does allow lookup by iCalUID).