# TypeError: calendar.getEvents is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using google apps script and attempting to check if an event exists. I'm using some code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026778/check-if-event-exists-before-adding-it-from-google-sheet-to-calendar) and I'm not sure why the script is telling me that getEvents() is not a function as it is here in [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar)
My code looks like this

```
function doesEventExist() {
  var fromDate = new Date(); //This is Today
  var toDate = new Date();
  toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+20);
  Logger.log("From "+fromDate+" to "+toDate);
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("CalendarName");
  if(calendar == null){
    Logger.log("Unable to connect to calendar");
    exit();  
  }
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate,toDate);

  for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++)
    {
      var ev = events[i];
      var title = calendar.getEventSeriesById(ev.getId()).getTitle();


      if (title.indexOf(Event Name)>-1){
        var start = ev.getStartTime();
        Logger.log("Found Event");
        return true;
          var id = ev.getId();
          var date = ev.getStartTime();
          var desc = ev.getDescription();

          }


    }
  }
```

Does the getEvents() function no longer exist or is there an issue with my code?

Edit: as someone commented getCalendarsByName() returns an array to I ended up setting the variable calendar to calendars[0]

Comment: It seems `CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName()` returns an array of calendars, so you would have to pick an element from the array to use `getEvents()` on: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarsByName(String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leaving @nbookmans [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682402/typeerror-calendar-getevents-is-not-a-function#comment110849224_62682402) as an answer for Stack workflow purposes.

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarsbynamename), `getCalendarsbyName()` returns:

> Calendar[] — all calendars with this name that the user can access

Which is an array of Calendars. In order to get the events, you have to iterate over the array.